# Center a bootstrap column in just a certain device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm leaning bootstrap, and I made this a row with two columns to stack each other.

On the large devices i want it to be like that:
[image: Large devices]

With the trophy a little to the top, as you can see.

But in mobile small and medium it's like that:
[image: mobile]

As you can see, the trophy isn't centered under the black div, **it's possible to center it just when the columns stack each other?**

html:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='subir col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1'>
        <div>
            <p class='titulo'>Liga Juizforana</p>
            <hr size='1' align='left'>
            <p class='subtit'>A Liga Juizforana tem o intuito de trazer campeonatos diversos para a cidade focando em League of Legends. A intenção do campeonato é a diversão de todos, tendo campeonatos sempre que possível para todos se interagirem, conhecerem e entrarem no cenário competitivo da cidade.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grandelogo col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4'>
        <img src='imagens/LigaJFLogo.png' border='0px' alt='LigaJFLogo' title='LigaJFLogo'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .grandelogo {
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Change the actual width according to your needs

Comment: Row elements are ment to be 12-slots, regarthles the resolution. On smaller resolutions, it will look for clases with -xs- in it, and go up to -ms-, -lg- and so on. In your example your div with class=subir is col-lg-6 (half row), and the logo is xs-3, md-3 and lg-4. In conjuction non of them adds 12 to the row so it's not ment to work or go down. Other question I have, is it possible to add the class 'text-center' on the second div to center the content no matter what the position is? and then work your col classes accordingly to your resolution need keeping in mind that 12-slot rule

Comment: text-align:center is making the image inside the div centered, and not the div centered according with the screen.

Comment: if there is no `.col-xs-*` present, the div will be the full width of the container, so centering the image inside the div will achieve exactly what OP wants, centering the image only for small resolutions

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any centering element. To center it in a div, just put `text-center` class in a div.grandelogo classes, that is a supported way to do it in bootstrap.

If you want to have it 100% width in small devices, help yourself with col-sm or col-md settings:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='subir col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1'>
        <div>
            <p class='titulo'>Liga Juizforana</p>
            <hr size='1' align='left'>
            <p class='subtit'>A Liga Juizforana tem o intuito de trazer campeonatos diversos para a cidade focando em League of Legends. A intenção do campeonato é a diversão de todos, tendo campeonatos sempre que possível para todos se interagirem, conhecerem e entrarem no cenário competitivo da cidade.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='grandelogo col-sm-12 col-lg-4 text-center'>
        <img src='imagens/LigaJFLogo.png' border='0px' alt='LigaJFLogo' title='LigaJFLogo'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this will make the image looks bigger and it will loose quality, i want it to be centered when it's mobile and small devices, and not centered (like the first picture) in medium and big devices

Comment: it will not affect the image itself, it's still same size as you have used, but however. If you don't want to have it centered all devices, just take out the `.text-cener` and add css described above my answer, `@media (max-width: 767px) { .grandelogo {  text-align:center; }}`